# Centering content in a modal (having a n00b moment)

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to center a 3x3 grid in a modal.  I've been stuck on this for a good portion of the day and can't seem to figure out why it won't center.  The content is being templated through a php foreach loop.  Heres the php.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row centerThemes">
        <div class="span12">
            <?php $themes = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]; ?>
            <?php foreach($themes as $theme):?>
                <div class="span3 themeChoice" data-feedback-selected="false" data-feedback-type="<?= $theme?>">
                    <img class="img-responsive feedbackImg" src="path here">
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you see, I have this class called centerThemes which I have been playing with. I'd show you the CSS, but everything I have been trying hasn't been working.  Setting the margin to `0 auto`, `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `auto`, `display:block`, and so on. Any yes, I'm using bootstrap but its an older version, where you have to use a class like 'span4' to make a 4 column section.

Not too sure what to do.

Any help is appreciated- thanks!

Comment: Please show the rendered HTML, as well as indicating the **specific** version of Twitter Bootstrap that you are using.

Comment: why not just div align center?

Comment: @Fred-ii- `align` is a dead concept

Comment: @RiggsFolly Silly moi, what was I thinking? Oh well, at least I got a reply; that counts for something. I guess it's back to the old drawing board for the W3 consortium then.

Comment: It's not supported in HTML5, AFAIK? It's also really, really bad form.

Answer (score 0):

`span` classes sound like Boostrap 2. 
For some weird reason if I embed the snippet grid won't display as desired so I'll just link the fiddle.

[Here's an example without PHP using Bootstrap2](https://jsfiddle.net/6ywmv765/3/)